# Python Regular Expressions Re.Search

Tags: python, regex

I am having issues figuring out what this regular expression means:

```
import re
if re.search('^(0*)$','010'):
    print 'match'
else:
    print 'no match'
```

I'm mainly confused about the 0* in the brackets, what does the 0* mean? Can anyone please help? I'm just starting to learn more about regular expressions, and I know what the other symbols in the code mean. The output is : "no match".

Hope someone can help.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: It means: '^' match from the beginning of the line, '(0*)' match zero-or-more '0' characters and store the matching characters for subsequent retrieval, and finally '$' match the end of the line. In other words, match empty lines or line containing only zeros. Using a capture group (an expression between parenthesis) is pointless in the example above, since it is not used... '^0*$' would achieve the same result.

Comment: It might be better if you state what you would like to do with this regex, especially since it relatively does a lot if broken down into its components.

Comment: It just says if it matches then print match otherwise print no match. I think I understand it now though, due to the ^ and $ (which means the whole line), it wouldn't match because zero or more '0's means it would have to match, so the second string could only be something like '00' or '000'. If you could clarify, that would be great. Thanks for your responses!

Comment: Some basic information. These symbols are quantifiers `*+?` and `{x,y}`. They specify a range of times something should match of the construct to thier immediate left. Any basic tutorial should help you with this.

Comment: Yes, because of the `^` and `$` anchors, the pattern will only match on a line consisting of *only* any number of zeroes - NOTE: including *none* (ie. the empty string).  
But if there's anything in the input string that's not a `0`, then it won't match.

Answer (score 1):

0* Matches on Zero or more 0. ^ and $ says that the Wohle String should Match and Not only partial.

Simple regex Basics with some examples: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Sorry just for pasting a link, its a pain to write them all down :-)

Comment: You may want to mention the differences between `*` `+` and `?` and possibly even `{m}` `{m,n}` as quantifiers